# Which functions and methods can i use inside a multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module since i have two programs of which one requires information from the other one. With this module i can run them both simultaneously and keep feeding information.
With some basic code the multiprocessing worked just fine. However copying in the process my own programs which basically keep creating information in matrix form seems to be a problem. The code stops at the line with the append method. Is it possible that you cannot use this method in a multiprocessing.process?
If so what can i use then? Is there a list of functions and methods usable in these processes?

Comment: `append` works just fine in multiprocessing. You have some other issue you've misdiagnosed.

Comment: Oh thanks it was indeed something else. Seems like i can't define global variables in functions within a multiprocessing.process. Since the list to be appended was defined as such a global variable it did not work. At least thats what i think because removing the global defination seems to solve the problem thenks for the quick response!

Comment: Processes don't share globals. Processes share very little, really. There's a ton of implicit copying involved in multiprocessing that makes the whole thing very confusing.

Comment: If you have to get something from one process to another, your best bet is to use a queue.  (Create it in the main process and pass it as an argument to the other process.). One process puts items on the queue, and the other process reads them from the queue.